# HTML::TokeParser - finding text between and after tags

Tags: html, perl, tags

I am trying to extract the following text from HTML page using the following code, but my code fails..

Budget            - $25,000,00

Gross(worldwide)  - $58,500,00

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use HTML::TokeParser;

my $content = <<HTML;
<h5>Budget</h5>
$25,000,000 (estimated)<br/>
<br/>

<h5>Opening Weekend</h5>
$727,327 (USA) (<a href="/date/09-25/">25 September</a> <a href="/year/1994/">1994</a>) (33 Screens)<br/>
<br/>

<h5>Gross</h5>
$28,341,469 (USA) (<a href="/date/08-05/">5 August</a> <a href="/year/2012/">2012</a>)<br/>&#163;2,344,349 (UK) (<a href="/date/05-18/">18 May</a> <a href="/year/1995/">1995</a>)<br/>&#163;1,732,123 (UK) (<a href="/date/04-16/">16 April</a> <a href="/year/1995/">1995</a>)<br/>$58,500,000 (Worldwide)<br/>$555,480 (Belgium)<br/>ESP 637,291,985 (Spain)<br/>
<br/>

<h5>Admissions</h5>
82,890 (Belgium)<br/>163,594 (France) (<a href="/date/03-28/">28 March</a> <a href="/year/1995/">1995</a>)<br/>410,811 (Germany) (<a href="/date/12-31/">31 December</a> <a href="/year/1995/">1995</a>)<br/>1,245,604 (Spain)<br/>
<br/>

<h5>Filming Dates</h5>
<a href="/date/06-16/">16 June</a> <a href="/year/1993/">1993</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href="/date/09-10/">10 September</a> <a href="/year/1993/">1993</a><br/>
<br/>
HTML

my $description = "";
my $tp = HTML::TokeParser->new(\$content) || die "Can't open: $!";

while (my $token = $tp->get_tag("h5")) {
    my $text = $parser->get_text();
    last if $text =~ /budget/i;
}
```

Comment: There are all kinds of issues with your code. I already changed the quoting from double quotes to heredoc because the string contains double quotes. It also contains the currency values which start with `$` turning them into variables when quoting is on, so you need `$fo = <<'HTML';`.

Comment: @simbabque - thank you for formatting the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant solution, but it works.

```
while (my $token = $tp->get_tag("h5")) {
    my $heading = $tp->get_text();
    $tp->get_tag("/h5");
    my $amount = $tp->get_trimmed_text =~ s/[^\d,\$]//gr;
    next unless $amount =~ m/\d/;
    say qq{$heading - $amount};
}
```

According to the [HTML::TokeParser docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser) you can get start and end tags with `get_tag`. After the start `<h5>` we can grab the heading, and move on to the closing `</h5>`. That one has a text node behind it, which contains the monetary value.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with regexps also.

```
while ( $content =~ s!<h5[^>]*>\s*(.+?)\s*</h5>\s*(\S+)(.*?)<br[^>]*>!!is ){
  my $h5text = $1;
  my $amount = $2;
  my $rest   = $3;
  if ($h5text =~ m!(Budget|Gross)!is){
     print "$h5text\t$amount\n";
  }
}
```